# Differents behaviours in chrome and Mozilla Firefox with same vue-charts dataset

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-composition-api, vue-chartjs

I'm expecting the result I get in Google chrome than Mozilla firefox, but in Mozilla firefox after using the quick-pivot library is painted differently in Mozilla firefox due to to mixing the posisitons of the pivoted array. All the code is explained in detail in [github](https://github.com/pat310/quick-pivot/issues/80)